# Problem with Advanced Search and Search Builder

Tags: search

We are using Civi (version 4.6.3) primarily as a case management tool.

In Advanced Search, when I try to create a query with more than one Custom Field Set used for two different Case Activities, the search falsely returns no results.

I recreated the error in demo -- I created two new custom fields to extend two different Case Activities for Housing Support Case Type :
1. Activity: Secure Temporary Housing
   Custom Field Set: case-housing1-test 
   Field: Housing Status (dropdown select options:Temporary Housing, Homeless)
2. Activity: Long-term Housing Plan
   Custom Field Set: case-housing2-test 
   Field: Is long term plan complete? (yes or no)
I created a new contact: Joe Jack, and then created a Housing Support Case for him. In Secure temporary housing activity, Housing Status, I selected "Homeless". In Long-term housing plan activity, I selected "yes" to the question "Is long term plan complete?" .
Now if you go to Advanced Search and do a search for Activities, housing status - Homeless, long term plan complete - yes,  the search returns no records. If you do a search for housing status - homeless, you get Joe Jack.  If you do a search for long term plan complete - yes, you get Joe Jack.  But if you do a search for both you get nothing.

I believe the reason for this is that it doesn't recognize that the two activities belong to the same case. I was able to pull the correct results in a custom report I created by creating a view  for each activity type and joining them in a SQL statement on case id.

Also,this is a separate issue, in Search Builder, when I search a custom field used for Activities where field IS NULL , it returns all records where that field IS NOT NULL but the value in the column shows the field is empty.
[image: screen shot 1 - gender is null]
 If I do the same search but instead ask for records where field IS NOT NULL, it returns all the same records but this time the actual value is displayed in the column.
[image: screenshot 2 - gender is not null]
This is also true for is empty, is not empty.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information. What is your civi version? What search screen are you using exactly? Can you provide a screenshot? Can you reproduce this problem on the demo site?

Comment: I am aware that in a localised version of civicrm the IS NULL is twice in the list. The first one meaning IS EMPTY which differs from IS NULL.